# Need to go through list of objects and set to each object unique timestamp - Android

Tags: android

I got a list of objects. I need to go through the list and for each item, I need to set unique timestamp value. How I can implement it?
Now if I understand right the computation makes in less than 1ms so in logs I see weird values.

Here is an example of the code.

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    list.add("three");
    list.add("four");
    list.add("five");
    list.add("six");
    list.add("seven");
    list.add("eight");
    list.add("nine");
    list.add("ten");
    for (String s : list) {
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        Log.d("timestamp", s + ts);
    }
```

Logs instead of 10 values it shows 2 equal values

```
D/timestamp: 1584554340
D/timestamp: 1584554340
```

Comment: Can you log the size of list and check if it is 10 or not? or else first use a generic for loop and see how many times i getting called

Comment: @ManojMohanty thanks I have found solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the iteration goes very fast. I decided to get a timestamp in the beginning of iteration and just make +1 with each loop.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    list.add("three");
    list.add("four");
    list.add("five");
    list.add("six");
    list.add("seven");
    list.add("eight");
    list.add("nine");
    list.add("ten");
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    for (String s : list) {
        Log.d("timestamp", tsLong.toString());
        tsLong++;
    }
```

In this case, each item got a unique timestamp. That implementation was needed to fill EXISTING db with objects who does not have timestamp value but need to have for present usage. So with help of that I will add unique timestamp to each user which i have in DB.